# Axioms of replacement / specification are used to define functions, but use expressions of the form p(x), which map objects to truth values. Circular?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, logic, set-theory

I'm working my way through Tao's Analysis I (best book ever) and got to Section 3.1 on ZF set theory. I was excited to put my understanding of functions on more fundamental grounding, but then I realized that the axioms of replacement and specification use expressions of the form $p(x)$ or $P(x,y)$, where $x$ and $y$ are objects and $p(x)$ and $P(x,y)$ are truth values / Booleans. This seems a bit circular, unless these types of expressions are defined on even more rigorous grounds in logic theory. Is this the case?

While solving another problem, I realized that $p(x)$ can't really be defined in terms of sets, since "$p(x)$ is a mapping from the set of objects to truth values" implies the existence of the set of all objects, which we know does not exist.

Perhaps I'm thinking about this sillily. How should I be thinking about these concepts?

Comment: Good observation. The $P(x)$ that occurs in the axiom schema of specification might look like a function $P$ applied to an argument $x$. But it's not. Instead, it's just a notation for "*some formula in the language of set theory that contains the variable $x$ as a free variable*". Set theory textbooks, like Jech's Set Theory, would spend some time defining the language of set theory, logical formulas, then free/bound variables, and explain metatheory. Tao doesn't go down to this level of detail: he just wants to teach you enough set theory to help make sense of the Analysis material.

Comment: $P(x)$ is called (informally) "property". It is explained in the Appendix, page 322: "Let P(x) be some statement depending on a
free variable x.". It is not a *function* in the sense of set theory: a set with a specific characteristic. It is an expression of the mathematical language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to rigorously understand what $ZFC$ is, you must understand several fundamental definitions. I haven’t read Tao’s book on analysis, so maybe he doesn’t introduce $ZFC$ in this way. However, I think understanding these definitions will help assuage your worries about circularity.

First, you should know what a first-order, one-sorted language is. (There are other kinds of languages, but to understand $ZFC$, you only need to know what a first-order, one-sorted language is.) Then, given a first-order, one-sorted language $\mathcal{L}$, you should know what $\mathcal{L}$-formulas, $\mathcal{L}$-sentences, and $\mathcal{L}$-structures are. You should also know what it means for an $\mathcal{L}$-structure to model an $\mathcal{L}$-sentence.

Here’s a somewhat informal overview of these definitions. I will use the word "set" several times during this overview, but don't worry about that too much for the moment.

A first-order, one-sorted language is a set of symbols. Each symbol is labeled as a “constant,” “function,” or “relation” symbol, and each function and relation symbol is assigned an “arity." For the moment, these are all just symbols, and the "constant/function/relation" and "arity" designations are just formalisms—these symbols are not to be understood as actual functions and relations themselves (yet). As one example, the language of groups is $\{e, \cdot \}$, where $e$ is a constant symbol and $\cdot$ is a function symbol with arity $2$. As another example, the language of set theory is $\{ \in \}$, where $\in$ is a relation symbol with arity $2$.

Fix a first-order, one-sorted language $\mathcal{L}$. An $\mathcal{L}$-formula is a combination of the symbols of $\mathcal{L}$ along with the basic logical symbols according to certain rules. The "basic logical symbols" are these: $\{ \wedge, \vee, \neg, \rightarrow, \leftarrow, \leftrightarrow, (, ), [, ],=, \forall, \exists \}$ (give or take a few depending on which author you're following), along with an unlimited amount of variable names, like $x$, $y$, and $z$. I won't explicitly lay out what the “certain rules'' are that govern what combinations of these symbols form valid $\mathcal{L}$-formulas, but I'll give you a few examples and non-examples.

Let $\mathcal{L} =\{e, \cdot \}$, where $e$ is a constant symbol and $\cdot$ is a function symbol with arity $2$. Examples of $\mathcal{L}$-formulas include

- $(e \cdot x = x) \wedge \neg (e \cdot e = e)$
- $x \cdot y = z \cdot z$
- $\forall x [e \cdot x = x]$.

Non-examples include

- $x \cdot x$
- $\neg x$
- $(((( \neg x(($.

An $\mathcal{L}$-sentence is an $\mathcal{L}$-formula that does not have free variables. With $\mathcal{L}$ as above, some examples of $\mathcal{L}$ sentences include

- $\forall x [e \cdot x = x]$
- $\exists x [\neg (x = e)]$
- $\forall x y [x = y]$.

and some non-examples include

- $x \cdot y = e$
- $\forall x [x \cdot y = e]$
- $\exists y [ x \cdot y = e]$.

An $\mathcal{L}$-structure is a set $D$ along with with interpretations of each of the constant, function, and relation symbols from $\mathcal{L}$ such that each constant symbol is interpreted as a specific element of $D$, each function symbol with arity $n$ is interpreted as a function $D^n \to D$, and each relation symbol with arity $n$ is interpreted as an $n$-ary relation on $n$. For example, if $\mathcal{L}$ is again the language of groups, any [magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)) (with the usual interpretations) is an $\mathcal{L}$-model.

An $\mathcal{L}$-structure $M$ models an $\mathcal{L}$-sentence $\varphi$ if and only if $\varphi$ is true in $M$ according to $M$'s interpretation of the symbols from $\mathcal{L}$.

Each axiom of $ZFC$ is an $\mathcal{L}$-sentence, where $\mathcal{L} = \{ \in \}$ is the language of set theory mentioned above. There are infinitely many axioms of $ZFC$, since the axiom schemas of separation and replacement each are captured by infinitely many $\mathcal{L}$-sentences (one for each $\mathcal{L}$-formula $p$ satisfying certain conditions).

Now, you might be concerned about how I was allowed to use the word "set" in the definitions above. The perhaps disappointing truth is that we can only write these definitions in the context of some metatheory. This metatheory might be $ZFC$, or it might be something else, but it must allow us to talk about collections of objects that resemble sets. So, in a way, you are correct that there is some circularity at the bottom of this. However, set theorists are not concerned with this circularity. To them, set theory is just another branch of math, just like algebra or analysis. Just as there is nothing stopping us from using a microscope to look at another microscope, there is nothing stopping us from using math to study math.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth response! Out of curiosity, where can I learn more about this area of math? I own a few books on basic logic and they seem rather dry and uninteresting (dozens of pages in, you're still converting basic English sentences into logical statements).

Comment: You’re welcome! I recommend sadly unfinished book The Foundations of Mathematics by Kenneth Kunen. It’s written in an engaging tone, it has a lot on set theory, and it’s focused on using logic as a foundation for math. You can find it online here: https://people.math.wisc.edu/~awmille1/old/m771-10/kunen770.pdf. You can also look at this study guide on how to teach oneself logic: https://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/. Good luck with your journey of studying logic!!

Comment: ^That study guide includes numerous good book recommendations.